# How to hash the password in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, password-encryption

Say I have a password in plain text and I want to check if it matches the password in the database. I used the `wp_hass_password()` function in a php file in my wordpress directory (just assume my password is 'abc123'):

```
$mypass = wp_hash_password("abc123");
echo $mypass;
```

However, the result does not match the one I saw in phpMyAdmin. Furthermore, the above `$mypass` changes every time I refresh the php file.

My question is: how can I obtain the correctly hashed password from the plain text in wordpress?

Comment: The hash will be unique eash time you generate one even with the same original text. See the manual for `$wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)` in order to test that a new string matches the originally hashed password

Comment: Or can't you use WP's function [wp_check_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you might be looking for is https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password.